# Running Foreach loop tasks simultaneously

Tags: azure, powershell, foreach

let's say that I have following piece of code which stops all servers that has test in their name. I just wrote the code fast so actually don't know if that would work (typos etc) but you probably get the idea of the loop.

```
 $VM1 = @()
$Allvms = Get-Azvm
foreach ($vm in $Allvms) {
    $server = $VM1 += Get-AzVM -Status | Where-Object {$_.name -like '*test'}
            $vmresoucegroup = $server.resourceGroup
            $vmsubscription = $server.subscriptionId
            $servername = $server.name 

Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "vmresoucegroup" -Name "$servername"

}
```

Because this is foreach loop, it goes vm one by one shuts them down. What are my option if I would want them to run simultaneously so instead going one by one script would start the shutdown process at the same time on all vms?

If there are many vms at the loop the process could take pretty long time run so this would make it faster.

Comment: take a look at [foreach -parallel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/)

Comment: Read that now few times + few another blogs and articles and are a bit confused. Should I replace ForEach loop with foreach-object -Parallel or add foreach-object -Parallel after initial loop? Something like this " $AllVMs | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "vmresoucegroup" -Name "$servername" } -ThrottleLimit 2" ?

Comment: The foreach-object parallel syntax is correct but remember now that you are piping the `$AllVMs` to foreach, you have to reference the object using `$_`

Comment: `ForEach-Object -Parallel` is an easy alternative as Otter comment but it requires PowerShell Core, it does not exist in Windows PowerShell. What PS Version are you running?

Comment: I think I got it to work. Have to do more testing now and confirm it

Comment: The official name, and the name in the docs is `Powershell` for v6+, `5.1` and older is `Windows Powershell`

Comment: I'm running Poweshell 7 and there  foreach -parallel works. I have also gotten it work so everyhting is now done.